# Why does Griffiths define the complex inner product differently?

Tags: hilbert-space, conventions, definition, mathematics, complex-numbers

I have just now noticed that Griffiths (in his book *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*) defines the complex inner product as

$$\big<z,w\big>~=~\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{z}_iw_i.$$

In all mathematics books (I study math and physics) I have ever come across, it is defined as

$$\big<z,w\big>~=~\sum_{i=1}^nz_i\overline{w}_i.$$

Maybe there is an answer to this question, maybe there isn't, but why on earth is this defined differently in physics than in math?

If this question just doesn't belong here, let me know and I will delete it and eat my frustrations for dinner :).

Comment: Been there, shouted at the walls, it's frustrating for sure but authors will stick to their own notations and editors will not try to check for consistency.

Comment: Mathematicians tend to complex conjugate the right term with a bar while physicists tend to complex conjugate the left term with * in the definition of inner products. However different authors have different preference.

In particular, Griffiths is more physicist than mathematician

Comment: @Secret I understand that, that's not the point. I just think it's outrageous that it's the way it is. I personally think physicists _use_ math as a tool, and should therefore take the tools as they come from the math factory.

Comment: There are many ways physicists use maths differently from a mathematician, for example whether you use $\theta$ or $\phi$ for the azimuthial angle in spherical coordinates depends on whether you are mathematician convention or physicist convention.

Comment: That point was originally in my question, but monsieur @Qmechanic deleted it.

Comment: You are welcome, frustration wise it's a toss up between typos,  and notional differences. What I do is just write it my way in my notes, keep changing authors notation to mine,  then at least I have one consistent, but less reliable source...... me:)

Comment: @B.Pasternak: No, I only edited tags.

Comment: @Qmechanic Oh wait sorry sir, you are right, this was Mr. Gert's doing. Unnecessary introduction. I don't agree at all.

Comment: To be clear, this has nothing to do with Griffiths. *All* of physics is standardized to this same notation. Moreover, this notation emerged *before* linear algebra was even a unified subject, so it's not as though the "math way" has some sort of priority.

Comment: A agree that M. Gert was a bit too quick with his scissors.  You can go back and replace the excised text.  The complete history is maintained.  You can copy/paste it back in.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Relax dude, it's just notation. Pick a side and get used to the notation used in that side. If you spend more time doing physics, choose the physicists. This is just the beginning of the many notational differences between mathematicians and physicists. In the future you'll have fun with whether or not there's an $i$ in the exponent when studying lie algebras, and where to put your $2\pi's$ when doing Fourier transforms. And don't get me started on the difference in notation in differential geometry...

Comment: @Secret That also depends if you on the continent or in the US.

Answer (score 9):

As a rule of thumb, in mathematics a complex inner product or [sesquilinear form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) is conjugate-linear/[antilinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map) in the second entry (in the tradition of listing the least complicated arguments first), while in physics it is the other way around: It is conjugate-linear in the first entry (in order to make contact to the Dirac [bra-ket notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation)).

Answer (score 2):

Its only the more elementary math textbooks that use the opposite convention.

Every physics book puts the conjugate first. And when you get to more advanced operator theory math books eventually everyone switches to the other convention because it does make things easier.

And the only reason math books do it the wrong way is so they can use the word sesquilinear. If saying that word isn't super important, then why not do it the way that eventually makes it easier.

It also is nice that then you conjugate on the left put the operator in the middle and then have the operator act on the right when you do an expectation value. Whereas saying 1+1/2 linear (sesquilinear) is **still** vague: it's a half linear half conjugate-linear operator.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it doesn't matter unless and until one of them is complex conjugated and the same is maintained throughout the course. Most books I have come across conjugate the first term.